# Way to let runner execute a bash script

Tags: bash, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I set a `GIT_STRATEGY` variable to `none` in a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. So a repository is not built in a deployment server automatically. So we avoid building the git repository with its all history etc. A `git-archive` command will be used instead.

This way only needed files will be copied from a GitLab server.

Now I am looking for the way to send the bash script to the runner.

As we know, the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is actually being sent to the runner. Isn't it a way to send the bash script to the runner too? Then I would make the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file just to start the bash script and have a job done.

Of course, I could put the commands to the yml, but there are some limitations then because of a yml syntax. I could also make the runner `scp` the file but this would be too complex. Any ideas?

### update

Let me try to approach what I am going to achieve. There are several bash script files. Each of them is a specific scenario of the deployment. For example, one pulls project files from GitLab, deletes files in a folder `public` and moves project files to it.

The other script file pulls project files from GitLab, moves the files to the folder and creates a backup.

The other script file pulls project files from GitLab, moves the files, creates backups and performs a database migration. Etc.

There are three hosts:

1. Local PC of an administrator.
2. Remote GitLab server
3. Remote deployment server that server websites. (It has Nginx or Apache)

One of the script files will be executed on the deployment server. There is a number of the script files so we must provide replacing the script file from time to time.

The question is how to bring the script file to the deployment server so the runner could run it?

Comment: Use `git archive` to extract the script from the same or a different repository?

Comment: We need more information about your setup here. Why can't you just use the repository as normal and put the script there? Why can't you use a custom docker image and put the script there?

Comment: @PhilippLudwig Because a web server on a deployment server doesn't need a .git repository :) I am looking for a way to deploy without creating the .git repository.

Comment: So your runner runs on your webserver and you want to `cp` your files to the destination directory? I really need more input to answer this question.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig I updated my question. You may read it. Thanks.